# How do I determine which of my friends also like a Page I like?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is there any way to show the amount of my friends who like a page with FQL? For example, if I like a page, how can I learn how many of my friends like that same page? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question title: you don't need to say you have a question, we sort of assume that, so make the title more specific to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an FQL query like this -

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '<YOUR PAGE ID>' AND uid IN
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

You need uid in the WHERE clause because that's the only indexable field for page_fan. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Answer (score -1):

What kind of page?

If its a Fan Page no.

Facebook doesn't make it easy to find out who likes a Fan Page. You can get the total count easily enough but not who. If you running an App, somewhat like a Fan Gate then you can in theory collect this data this way, but you cannot do it with FQL. Its just not available.

Perhaps the relevant social plugin might help, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. It's definitely possible, with the right permissions, and a social plugin isn't what he's after at all.

Comment: The page_fan stuff must be new. I was under the assumption you could not get the Page Fans easily. And I did say might. I wasn't expecting it would help

Comment: It's not new, it's been around since the dawn of Pages. The important distinction is that you have to be *friends* with those users in order to determine if they're fans, hence the `friends_likes` permission I documented [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166157/how-do-i-determine-which-of-my-friends-also-like-a-page-i-like/7183342#7183342).

Comment: Ah. *headdesk* I jumped to "people I don't know" over "friends"